# What validation does Google do for EditText with android:inputType="textEmailAddress"

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am trying to locate the default input behavior (rules) for when         android:inputType="textEmailAddress".  I am not looking to add new checks.  I just want to know what restrictions an EditText with this input type has by default.  I have not been able to locate the rules coded for various input types in Android source code and I don't see this specific question asked anyplace else.  Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If you specify the input type for each text field in your app, the system displays the appropriate soft input method (on-screen keyboard).

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/style
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/search/label/Input%20methods

there won't be restrictions applied to the edittext input, its just for the soft keyboard to show @ or .com as a convenience. The input method is useful for some specific things like numeric only, password etc. You will have to use a pattern/regex to check if its a valid email address or not